# Допустимо ли так искуственно выделять свой вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение

> --->Запись результата, от регулярных выражений в файл<---

[Сам вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197969/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB)

Что делать в таких ситуациях?

Править ли вопрос?

UPD: Заголовок уже поправили, но вопрос по этой теме - остается открытым.

Comment: Мне кажется заголовок и сейчас какой-то странный. Запятая там явно лишняя, да и вся формулировка корявая. Подозреваю, что его еще не раз кто-нибудь поправит

Comment: Ну, я скорее про первоначальные ---> <---

Comment: В принципе, вы можете писать что угодно, но подобные символы, скажем так, необычны.

Comment: Меня такой заголовок только оттолкнёт от вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Подобные выделения и исправления преследуют всего лишь одну цель - чтобы вопрос увидело больше людей, и следовательно увеличился шанс получения ответа. Вообще, для поднятия вопроса в списке достаточно любой правки текста/заголовка или меток. Вероятно, автор этого не знает и пытается для целей увеличения просмотров добавить какое-то эксклюзивное оформление в заголовок. Делать этого, однозначно, не стоит. Любое поднятие вопроса путём бессмысленных правок (никак не улучшающих сообщение) не рекомендуется. За злоупотребление этим механизмом может последовать предупреждение от модераторов или даже бан. Предусмотренный способ привлечения дополнительного внимания к вопросу на сайте - объявление [конкурса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). Правки, ухудшающие сообщение, вполне допустимо откатывать, но это, в свою очередь, тоже приводит к поднятию вопроса в списке. Если автор продолжает дёргать вопрос путём бессмысленных правок - время отметить такое сообщение тревогой для привлечения модераторов.